# How do I call a method in a web service class once a day?

Tags: c#, web-services

I've got a method in some class of a web service, but this isn't the webmethod and I need to call it once a day.

Is there an easy way than using Windows services or windows task scheduler? I'm new using C# and developing web services.

Comment: Put it on a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @paqogomez Who's gonna start that? I don't know how timer would help in web service

Comment: @paqogomez that won't work if the service remains idle long enough for it to spin down in IIS.

Comment: If it is not a webmethod, how do you plan on calling it?

Comment: The method is in a partial class of the web service, the idea is that the method by itself send the transferences that the web method failed

Comment: Check with your hosting company. Mine offer a simple scheduler, I can tell the scheduler to call a specific url every X time. That URL would call your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would either create a webmethod that does what you want to do, then build a console app that calls the web method and schedule it, or move the relevant code into a shared assembly, then build a console app that uses that code and schedule it.

Either way, I would recommend using Windows Scheduler or another scheduling tool versus a timer or service - they're simple to set up and it's what they're designed for.

Comment: Thanks, I think is the best way. I'll try to do it, and I'll tell you.